Criteria builder between() time bounds
My code:
predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.between(
    root.get("date"),
    criteriaBuilder.literal(Timestamp.valueOf(LocalDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC).minusMinutes(5))), 
    criteriaBuilder.literal(Timestamp.valueOf(LocalDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC).minusMinutes(1)))
));

If the current time is 10:05 AM, then the time bounds are between 10:00 AM and 10:04 AM. My question is, will this predicate consider timestamps up to 10:04:59.999, or just up to 10:04:00.000?
Thank you!

Your code doesn't match your question. If the current time is 10:00, the bounds are 9:55 and 9:59.

@Sören Sorry! I edited now.

The API documentation says it checks if the 1st argument is between the 2nd and 3rd argument, without stating if it's a closed or half-open range, so that's not helpful. However, I imagine it gets translated to an SQL BETWEEN clause, and the SQL standard specifies that the start and end are both inclusive. (By the way, I assume you mean "up to 10: 03 :59.999". If you actually mean 10:04:59.999, then no it doesn't go up to that.)

Note that if the current time is 10:05:00.000, LocalDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC).minusMinutes(1)) will be 10:04:00.000 so there is no way that the "between" criteria would go up to 10:04:59 since that would be after the specified end time. When you say the current time is "10:05", if by that statement you mean that it's actually something between 10:05:00 and 10:05:59.999, then yes it could go up to 10:04:59.999 as one minute earlier than 10:05:59.999 would be 10:04:59.999.
